# Programatically create UITableView() with loadView Position and size ambiguous

Tags: swift

I want to set my view to be a UITableView without adding to the main view, that is I don't want to call **self.view.addSubview(tableView)**

However, my loadView() does not seem to be working - the position and size of the tableView are ambiguous...

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let tv = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)
    tv.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.translucentLightGrey
    tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.backgroundColor = .red
    view = tv
    tableView = tv
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -0).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

How can I set the tableview as the view?

Comment: Try deleting the constraints. You shouldn't need them.

Comment: just put code in to dispatch queue with 0.01 second delay

Comment: If you are trying to let the main view of the view controller to be the table view, then you should not even worry about its constraints, but (obviously) you should worry about its subviews' constraints.

Comment: as an advice try https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit